# How to subtract two dates (from 2 columns in database) in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, hour

I have to make in my model a query to order by this subtraction between two dates. 
I have to calculate subtraction between columns `ordersheader.transportDate` and `orderitems.forecast_hour`. These are in 2 tables - `ordersheader` and `orderitems`. I've joined them ON `idOrder`.
First, I have to find max(`orderitems.forecast_hour`) for each idOrder and then to subtract `ordersheader.transportDate` - this max value from `orderitems.forecast_hour` for each idOrder. It should be calculated in hours because it's the same date.
It should be displayed first, these idOrders which `orderitems.transportDate` - this max `orderitems.forecast_hour` < 0. 
I tried with this but it gave me error:

```
Call to undefined function DATEDIFF
```

Ho to do that?

```
<?php
 function getOrders(){
            $date = new DateTime("now");
            $curr_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
            $this->db->select('orderitems.eggSize as size');
            $this->db->select('ordersheader.*,customer.name,GROUP_CONCAT(orderitems.itemNumber) as itemNumber');
            $this->db->select('ordersheader.*,customer.name,ordersheader.*,customer.name,GROUP_CONCAT(orderitems.quantity ) as quantity ');
            $this->db->select('ordersheader.*,customer.name,ordersheader.*,customer.name,GROUP_CONCAT(orderitems.unitPrice) as unitPrice');
            $this->db->select('ordersheader.*,customer.name,ordersheader.*,customer.name,GROUP_CONCAT(orderitems.eggSize ) as eggSize');
            $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(orderitems.forecast_hour) as forecast_hour');
            $this->db->from('ordersheader'); 
            $this->db->join('orderitems', 'orderitems.idOrder = ordersheader.idOrder');
            $this->db->join('customer', 'customer.idCustomer = ordersheader.idCustomer');
            $this->db->where('DATE(orderDueDate)', $curr_date);
            $this->db->group_by('orderitems.idOrder');
            $this->db->order_by(DATEDIFF('hour', 'ordersheader.transportDate', 'orderitems.forecast_hour'));
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
        }
```

Comment: For what it's worth, when doing more complicated queries, like the one you are attempting to do, I usually just write out the SQL into a string variable and then have code igniter execute that. I find the active records class to be okay for simple things, but cumbersome for more complex tasks,

Comment: Ok, I'll have to write it in variable. But Is it possible to use date_diff when dates are from database? :) Or in this case what should I use?

Comment: Yes it is possible, MySQL has a `DATEDIFF` function. You should perform your calculation in the SQL and not in PHP. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: I did it with select :)  $this->db->select('ordersheader.transportDate - MAX(orderitems.forecast_hour) as diff'); and then : $this->db->order_by('diff','ASC');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following changes. DATEDIFF needs to be in your SELECT line:

```
$date = new DateTime("now");
$curr_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
$this->db->select('orderitems.eggSize as size');
$this->db->select('DATEDIFF("hour", "ordersheader.transportDate", "orderitems.forecast_hour") AS MyDateDiff'); //ADD THIS
$this->db->select('ordersheader.*,customer.name,GROUP_CONCAT(orderitems.itemNumber) as itemNumber');
$this->db->select('ordersheader.*,customer.name,ordersheader.*,customer.name,GROUP_CONCAT(orderitems.quantity ) as quantity ');
$this->db->select('ordersheader.*,customer.name,ordersheader.*,customer.name,GROUP_CONCAT(orderitems.unitPrice) as unitPrice');
$this->db->select('ordersheader.*,customer.name,ordersheader.*,customer.name,GROUP_CONCAT(orderitems.eggSize ) as eggSize');
$this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(orderitems.forecast_hour) as forecast_hour');
$this->db->from('ordersheader');
$this->db->join('orderitems', 'orderitems.idOrder = ordersheader.idOrder');
$this->db->join('customer', 'customer.idCustomer = ordersheader.idCustomer');
$this->db->where('DATE(orderDueDate)', $curr_date);
$this->db->group_by('orderitems.idOrder');
$this->db->order_by(MyDateDiff); //EDIT THIS

$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: It gave me this: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF' and it should be order_by('MyDateDiff'); group_by should be the same.

Comment: ah yes oops, thats what i meant

Comment: It gives me this message: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: how are you saving these dates in your database? are they DATETIME, DATE, TIMESTAMP ?

Comment: Columns are of type datetime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81981/discussion-between-ci-lover-and-codegodie).